# Solving a fourth degree polynomial over C.

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers

I have the following polynomial:
$$2z^4 - 4z^3 + 21z^2 - 36z + 27$$

One factor is $z - 3i$.  I need to find all the other roots.  How would I go about doing this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $\alpha\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\mathbb{R}$ is a root of $p(x)\in\mathbb{R}[x]$ implies that $\overline{\alpha}$ is a root too, and $\frac{q(x)}{(x-\alpha)(x-\overline{\alpha})}$ is a quadratic polynomial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the other factor must be $$z+3i$$ since the coefficients are all real
your equation can be written as
$$(9+z^2)(3-4z+2z^2)=0$$

Comment: Are there not more factors?  I assumed that being a fourth degree polynomial there would be four roots.

Comment: you can divide by $$z^2+9$$ and you will get a quadratic polynomial

Comment: How do you divide by z^2 + 9?

Comment: @ThreeOneFour https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division

Comment: Is there a way to use the factor theorem to solve it?

Answer (score 3):

As the coefficients are real, $z+3i$ is also a factor. So the polynomial is divisible by $z^2+9$.